# Meaning of XX below Slat FLap Trim on A350 with flap setting 1

Tags: airbus-a350, slats

What is the meaning of the 'XX' in amber below the 1 (in green) within the Slat Flap Trim section on the A350 PFD when the flaps are set to 1 with the correct speed (below 255kts)?

See picture attached. If the flaps would have failed, it would indicate XX without the 1. So, what else could this XX indicate? [image]

Answer (score 4):

The number below the flap indication is not the position of the flaps/slats, but the position of the flap lever. When the lever is moved, the number becomes cyan indicating that the flaps/slats are in transit and when they have reached the selected position the number becomes green.

Edit: As per FCOM, there is no mention of amber XX indication for flap lever position at all. Checked in a simulator that total computer failure will not cause indication to turn XX.

Comment: This sounds quite reasonable. Do you have some references to support your claim?

Comment: I edited my answer. The reference is FCOM DSC-27-20-30. Don't know if there is one available online. Other buses have similar architecture and indications, so you might want to check those from www.smartcockpit.com, for example.

Comment: Did you try holding the lever in between detents?

Answer (score -3):

Thats your landing gear indication. The display unit is not receiving data for it. Normally when the gear is up nothing is shown.

Comment: You should add references and links to support your answer. Note that this links may provide further reading to dig into the subject of this question.

Comment: Why so many downvotes on a post by a new contributer. I can't judge the correctness of the answer, it could very well be right. Yes, references should be included, but that's hardly a reason to downvote. If somebody has the evidence that this answer is faulty,  they should leave a comment with the evidence. @A350Mechanic, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com